# Como inserir mensagem de erro no Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu criei um js para exibir os resultados conforme a pesquisa e o código funciona perfeitamente, conforme exemplo abaixo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".blocos").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    $('.linhas').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="busca"><input id="myInput" placeholder="Filtrar por nome" type="text" /></div>

<p class="blocos"> azul </p>
<p class="blocos"> verde </p>
<p class="blocos"> amarelo </p>
```

O que eu preciso é que seja exibida uma mensagem de erro quando o usuário digitar um termo que não existe no conteúdo dentro de blocos, se o usuário digitar ver (ele logo vai exibir o verde, pois ele existe dentro do contexto) mas se o usuário digitar "veg" ele deveria retornar uma mensagem de erro). Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione um elemento contento a mensagem de erro (no exemplo, utilizei um `span`).

Adicione um contador antes do `filter`, para armazenar o número de ocorrências que deram sucesso na busca, se não tiver nenhuma ocorrência esse contador vai conter o valor 0. Então aplique o `toggle` usando a condição do contador, se ele for igual a zero é pq não teve nenhuma ocorrência, então mostre a mensagem de erro, caso contrário esconde a mensagem de erro.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var count = 0;
    $(".blocos").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
      count += $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 ? 1 : 0;
    });
    $("span").toggle(count == 0);
    $('.linhas').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
span{
 color: red;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="busca"><input id="myInput" placeholder="Filtrar por nome" type="text" /></div>

<p class="blocos"> azul </p>
<p class="blocos"> verde </p>
<p class="blocos"> amarelo </p>

<span>Não encontrado</span>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, era isso mesmo, obrigadão!